# Shopware 6 Products with Custom fields type

Tags: custom-fields, shopware6

In the backend I have several custom fields defined, which are all select types, these are connected to the products. Now I want to display the values of the selected options of product.customFields in the detail page.

I can dump the product.customFields and get an array like so:

```
    product.customFields array [
       technical_name_select_field_1 => option_xxx
       technical_name_select_field_2 => option_123
 ]
```

Now how do I get the value that is stored in custom_field as a json object which is indicated with name = technical_name_select_field_1 and config = {{"type": "select", "label": {"de-DE": "Wert für option xxx", "en-US": "Value for option xxx", "nl-NL": "Waarde optie xxx" ), "value": "option_xxx" },  etc, etc.

When I write {{ attribute(product.translated.customFields,'technical_name_select_field_1')|sw_sanitize }} in the template I get option_xxx printed. But I'd like to see the label value "Value for option xxx" and the like.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, there are no direct connections between custom fields definition and custom fields values in any entity.

I can suggest you, to subscribe `sales_channel.product.loaded` and extend product data with info that you need.

In subscriber, you can directly call custom_field repository and search definition by the technical name of custom fields, that you have as keys in product data.

Comment: Hi i also have this problem, can you maybe explain a little more on how to do this? I'm new to shopware. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Sanne, What exactly you want to know, how to subscribe to an event or retrieve data from the custom_field repo?

Comment: Hi @Valerrii, yeah i don't have a clue where to start so both i guess? I currently have in my twig file:                                   {{ product.translated.customFields.migration_attribute_4_streek_154 | trans }} so that results in option_234

Comment: Alright, you can check \Shopware\Core\Content\Product\SalesChannel\SalesChannelProductSubscriber to understand how to create a subscriber on that even. In the constructor, you should pass `custom_field.repository` to your own subscriber. In `loaded` method you can collect custom fields` technical name and find its definition using the repository. After that, you can add any information into your product data(entities), I prefer to add it to extension, as Shopware Entity is an instance of Shopware\Core\Framework\Struct.